# ZwCreateFile/ZwOpenFile and STATUS_SHARING_VIOLATION

Tags: windows, kernel, driver

I need to read SQL Server database files opened by server (with exclusive access I guess). After some research I figured that there are two options: with Volume Shadowcopy Service or kernel mode driver. So I implemented first option, but there are issues: it works as backup, it waits for some time to get access and database files can be greater than 1TB.
So I'm trying to read files with kernel mode driver, but whatever option I trying with

```
  TraceEvents(TRACE_LEVEL_VERBOSE, DBG_INIT, "Absolute Filename %wZ", &absFileName);
  InitializeObjectAttributes(&fileAttributes, &absFileName, 
    OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE | OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE, 
    NULL,
    NULL
  );

  status = ZwCreateFile(
    &devExt->FileHandle,
    SYNCHRONIZE | FILE_READ_DATA,
    &fileAttributes,
    &ioStatus,
    NULL,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
    FILE_OPEN,
    FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT,
    NULL,
    0
  );

  if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
    TraceEvents(TRACE_LEVEL_ERROR, DBG_INIT, "ZwCreateFile failed with status %!STATUS!", status);
    devExt->FileHandle = NULL;
  }
```

or

```
  status = ZwOpenFile(
    &devExt->FileHandle,
    SYNCHRONIZE | FILE_READ_DATA,
    &fileAttributes,
    &ioStatus,
    FILE_SHARE_READ,
    FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT
  );
```

I have error `ZwCreateFile failed with status 0xc0000043(STATUS_SHARING_VIOLATION)`. Is it even possible to read such files from driver. If I restricted to ordinal access rules even in driver then how antiviruses able to read such files. Anything can open something in exclusive mode and block access.
Driver based on Microsoft's example `Windows-driver-samples\general\ioctl\kmdf\`.

Comment: for what you need kernel driver here ?! no matter from which mode called open file - sharing violation is sharing violation. maximum which you can try - use `FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS`

Comment: When I was searching how to open server database files already opened by server people said: you need VSS or Kernel mode driver. So I decided to try.

Comment: no, this is big mistake. result of sharing violation - not depend from kernel/user mode. and any vss - no sense use - not any other api for create file anyway

Comment: It works with VSS. With FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS same error and by `FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS 0x00000007` it is combined flag of FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE

Comment: I guess reading at kernel mode driver level means reading at block level. "VSS operates at the block level of volumes", "Open File Manager is a highly efficient file snapshot tool, working at the block level".

Comment: for STATUS_SHARING_VIOLATION doesn't matter from user or kernel mode you open file

Comment: I mean for me to solve the problem it means not just reading file with kernel mode driver but using NTFS/FAT32 libraries to read at block level. If they even exists. Or doing it myself by documentations.